# Hide div after selecting option in select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three options in a `select`. I want that when I select `optionB`, a div with an `id` of `demo` should be hidden. How can I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectOption').select(function() {
    var ab = $('#selectOption').val();
    if (ab == 'optionB') {
      $("#demo").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectOption'>
  <option>--select</option>
  <option value='optionA'>optionA</option>
  <option value='optionB'>optionB</option>
</select>

<div id='demo'>xyz</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After twelve previous questions, you should be formatting correctly by now.

Comment: ok next time, I will remind this

Comment: Use `change()` not `select()` and your code will work. `select()` is used for when a user makes a text selection with the mouse.

Comment: thanks, after changing change(), it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#selectOption").on("change",function(){
        
        if($(this).val() == "optionB" )
            
             $("#demo").hide(1000);
        
    })
    
})
```

```html
<select id='selectOption'>
    <option>--select</option>
    <option value='optionA'>optionA</option>
    <option value='optionB'>optionB</option>
</select>

<div id='demo'>xyz</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the "select" event for the "change" event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#selectOption').on("change", function() {
    var ab = $('#selectOption').val();
    if (ab == 'optionB') {
      $("#demo").hide();
    } else {
      $("#demo").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectOption'>
  <option>--select</option>
  <option value='optionA'>optionA</option>
  <option value='optionB'>optionB</option>
</select>

<div id='demo'>xyz</div>
```

Comment: Didn't do the voting, but I'd guess because it doesn't reappear?

Comment: No one said it should reapper after kkkkk